# config.txt has no effect on the bash screen with archlinux arm

Tags: pi-3, display, archlinux, config.txt

I have:

rpi3 v2.0

http://os.archlinuxarm.org/os/ArchLinuxARM-rpi-3-latest.tar.gz

the boot is on a FAT32 2gb sd card and the root is on a EXT4 8gb USB flash drive

crt tv connected with an rca cable

It runs without any problems but when editing overscan or sdtv_mode or anything else in the /boot/config.txt file it takes effect only in the boot screen 
but as soon as it starts to enter the tty it loses my configurations and runs in a very ugly way not fitting the screen.

What can I do?